# Javascript/Node - Question about calling functions from within same module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hoping somebody could please explain this to me- why can I call the second function from the first without error in the first 2 examples, but the third example errors out.

**I can write a module like so:**

```
function main () {
   const double = doubleThis(5)
   console.log(double);
}

function doubleThis(num) {
   let answer = num*2;
   return answer;
}
```

**or like this:**

```
module.exports = {
   run: function(){
      const double = doubleThis(5);
      console.log(double);
   }
}

function doubleThis(num){
   let answer = num*2
   return answer;
}
```

**However, something like this is not allowed:**

```
module.exports = {
   run: function(){
      const double = doubleThis(5);
      console.log(double);
   }, 
   
   doubleThis: function(num){
      let answer = num*2;
      return answer;
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. Hoisting. 2. Inside an object's method, you cannot refer to functions by name and you have to use `this`

Comment: because `doubleThis` wouldn't be a function to it

Comment: @VLAZ I don't see how this is related to hoisting.

Comment: Btw, `answer = num*2;` is missing a declaration and should throw an exception in a strict mode module.

Comment: @Bergi the question is not entirely clear. OP is asking "how does it work". Without any guidance for *what* works or why they were asking. I've listed all the relevant things - in the first one hoisting may be involved. Again, really hard to judge based on the question. Now *with an answer*, it seems it was just "how do I call a method on an object" rather than "explain how this code works" but I could not really guess that's what OP really meant.

Comment: fixed the missing declaration - the purpose of the question was basically, why does calling the method work in the first two examples but not the third, where both methods are contained within the module.exports object. What I gather is that you need to use `this` when calling methods from within the same object?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, `this.doubleThis(5)` works fine- embarrassing question but maybe somebody else might wonder same thing. I'm familiar with usage of `this` in prototypes but apparently not familiar enough with how this applies everywhere else... will review hoisting. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/4987197) to better understand the `this` keyword